# ASP.NET Core Post results to email

Tags: asp.net-core

Let me start out by saying that I am brand new to ASP in general. I am a little better than a novice when it comes to C# coding. However, I am in my Capstone class at Liberty Online and the class before this required us to come up with a programming idea. When I made this I was thinking of using just HTML but as time went on I settled on ASP.

I have created the cshtmls and wired it up. Now I am working on making some of the gears moving. Right at this moment, I have some forms that a user is to fill out. Now I want to have an email sent to the owner once the user has submitted the form. I have looked around for a couple of days on was to do this but it appears that most code about email is just that email.

What I am looking for is to just send the result to the owner. Can anyone point me to a resource that will help me with this? I must be using the wrong search words.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this tutorial from microsoft extends your needs, as it is about identity and authentication, but it really helped me and i am using the email provider in some projects.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/accconfirm?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio